# View Release's ArtifactsDirectory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When a Release is executed in VSTS the first step downloads the build artifacts to the System.ArtifactsDirectory directory.

I have a step in my release tasks that creates a new file at this location.

In troubleshooting I'd like to verify this file was properly created.
How can I view the files in this release Artifacts directory?

I can view log files, but no view onto the actual release files.

Comment: Can you view files in Artifacts directory now?

Comment: @Marina not sure what you mean, did the system change since my post? Also just to clarify, i'm looking for Release artifacts, not Build. I can see the Build artifacts fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a PowerShell task and run `Get-ChildItem`. Or a command line task and run `dir`.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I thought of that as well and ended up doing that (marked yours as the answer). But I'm still interested in knowing if there is a VSTS feature I'm missing, or maybe I should add a suggestion.

Comment: @JohnKoz I don't see that it's a missing feature. You can run any script or command line task you want.